Opening Flush Light Fixture Cover
I have these light fixtures in my condo that needs the light replaced. I cant seem to find an instruction manual/video on how to open the cover. It seems to be a flush light fixture with a single screw. Anyone open one of these?


Is that a screw head on the upper left?

On some of these type of fixtures, the whole cover unscrews from the holder.

The screw may just be a set screw, with the shade supported by tabs or other bits not visible from the outside. Try loosening the screw, then rotating the shade counter-clockwise — likely a third- or quarter-turn.

@JonCuster - yeah a single screw!

@SteveI: Will try that! There are indented tabs/small openings like the one above around the holder

There are only so many ways to hold a cover in place, you just have to keep thinking creatively. If it moves just a bit, try to figure out what is preventing it. Silicone spray (not the oily kind) can help if it is stuck from not being opened for a long time. Or just give it a good whack — with something wood or plastic, less likely to break it.

If there are three or four points around the circle (tabs, etc) that usually means it comes out either by retracting the 'points' (screws) or turning the entire shade. If there are no obvious tabs or attachment points on the metal part, particularly if the shade is plastic, it may be friction-fit or have tabs on the plastic shade you can just pull straight down.

Undo the screw
This should allow the cover tilt down at that side and come undone on the other side

Tried that and tried turning the shade to no avail

That is the way for square fixtures. This one is round.
